# Spring Validation Annotations Order

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I want to ask is it possible to set explicitly the validation order in Spring. I mean, I have this command object:

```
public class UserData {
 @NotBlank
 private String newPassword;

 @NotBlank
 private String confirmPassword;

 @Email(applyIf="email is not blank")
 @NotBlank
 private String email;

 @NotBlank
 private String firstName = "";

 private String middleName = "";

 @NotBlank
 private String lastName = "";

        // getters/setters
}
```

and I display my error messages on top of the page like this:

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="${userData}">
   <ul class="errors">
      <c:forEach items="${errors.allErrors}" var="error">
       <li><spring:message message="${error}"/></li>
   </c:forEach>
  </ul>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

The problem is no matter what my error messages are displayed in the following order:

> ```
> * Fill you last name.
> * Fill you password.
> * Fill your emailaddress.
> * Fill you password again.
> * Select your gender.
> * Fill your first name.
> ```

It is not random, because this order is preserved every time. It is not alphabetical, or any other order... I am really stuck. Can someone help please?

Comment: It may not be Spring responsible for this, it may be the underlying validation implementation, e.g. hibernate validator.

Comment: We are using ver. 0.93 of the Spring annotation-based bean validation framework hosted on java.net

Comment: Which one is that?  java.net is a big place...

Comment: https://springmodules.dev.java.net/
The validation module specificly.

Answer (score 3):

SpringModules is a dead project, it's no longer supported. If you need JSR-303 validation support in Spring, I suggest using the reference implementation, [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html), and [wire it up like so](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring).

Having said that, this may not fix your problem, but at least you'll be using up-to-date libraries, likely making it easier to fix.

Comment: I know this post is old, but I ran into this issue using Spring 4 w/ hibernate validator 5.0.1.  Haven't yet found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that using @GroupSequence works, though it doesn't feel like a proper solution.

See http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using for a quick tutorial.